# ¿Cómo bajar de encima del enemigo? Unity2D + C#

Tags: c#, unity2d

Hay ocasiones en los que mi player se queda encima de mi enemigo y viceversa. Usé el siguiente código para bajar a mi enemigo de mi player y viceversa pero solo funciona si NO hay una pared justo al lado.

```
void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    //evitar que el player se quede de pie encima del enemigo
    if (collision.HasTag("Enemy"))
    {
        // colisionó por la parte superior del player 
        if (Mathf.CeilToInt(n.y) == 1 && !isFrontWall )//seguir recto     
        {
            isOnEnemy = true;

            if (direction == Vector2.right)
            {
                canMoveToRight = true;
            }
            else if (direction == Vector2.left)
            {
                canMoveToLeft = true;
            }
            return;
            
        }
        
        else if (Mathf.CeilToInt(n.y) == 1 && isFrontWall )//dar la vuelta
        {
            isOnEnemy = true;

            if (direction == Vector2.right)
            {
                canMoveToLeft = true;                    
            }
            else if (direction == Vector2.left)
            {
                canMoveToRight = true;
            }
            return;                
        }

    }
    else { isOnEnemy = false;  }        
}
```

Cuando hay una pared al lado el sprite empieza a "flipar" como uno loco de un lado para el otro XD... La variable "isFrontWall" es un rayCast que puse para saber si hay o no hay pared al lado.

También he intentado hacelo asi:

```
void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.With("Tilemap"))
    {
        boxCollider.isTrigger = false;
    }

    if (collision.HasTag("Enemy"))
    {
        Vector3 n = collision.GetNormal();

        if (Mathf.CeilToInt(n.y) == 1)
        {
            boxCollider.isTrigger = true;
        }
    }
}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    boxCollider.isTrigger = false;
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    boxCollider.isTrigger = false;
}
private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    boxCollider.isTrigger = false;
}
```

Lo anterior "casi" funciona bien, pero a veces si el sprite cae en una esquina entre el suelo y la pared y Unity no detecta bien las colisiones y el sprite ataviesa el suelo. Es decir que tampoco  sirve. (Hay un gran problema con las paredes y las esquinas en Unity).

¿alguna idea de como solucionar esto?
Gracias!!

Comment: Unity tiene un foro de soporte con una enorme comunidad, y lo mejor de todo es que, mientras que aquí ***seguro*** que *algunos* conocen unity y han trabajado bastante con él... en el foro de unity, ***TODOS*** saben de lo que hablan. La pregunta está bien planteada, pero, personalmente, creo que los foros de soporte propios de cada aplicación son el lugar más indicado para empezar a preguntar, más en concreto porque esto no es tanto un problema del lenguaje C#, como del motor de unity en si

Comment: Muchas gracias Benito!! Buscaré en el foro de Unity a ver si encuentro algo.